# Упростить проверку словаря: есть ли указанные ключи и не пустые значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно упростить этот код?

В options должны быть данные ключи и они не должны быть пустыми. Слишком длинный if тоже не хочу писать, подскажите как это можно упростить?

```
try:
    if (not options['gatewayUrl']) or (not options['clientId']) or (not options['secretKey']):
        raise ConfigurationException('API connection data not set')
except KeyError:
    raise ConfigurationException('API connection data not set')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [set.issubset()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set%20issubset#set):

```
chk = set(['gatewayUrl','clientId','secretKey'])
chk.issubset(set(options)) and all(options.values())
```

Примеры:

```
# значение для ключа "secretKey" не определено

In [178]: options = {'gatewayUrl':'url', 'clientId':'id', 'secretKey':None}

In [179]: chk.issubset(set(options)) and all(options.values())
Out[179]: False

# все OK

In [180]: options = {'gatewayUrl':'url', 'clientId':'id', 'secretKey':'secret'}

In [181]: chk.issubset(set(options)) and all(options.values())
Out[181]: True

# отутсвует ключ "secretKey"

In [182]: options = {'gatewayUrl':'url', 'clientId':'id'}

In [183]: chk.issubset(set(options)) and all(options.values())
Out[183]: False
```

Comment: А проверку на пустоту ключей прописать в if?

Comment: @RomanKravets, об этом я забыл - сейчвс поправлю...

Comment: @RomanKravets: если в `options` могут быть ключи не из `chk` и их значения не ограничены, то чтобы проверить, что только указанные ключи обязаны непустое значение иметь: `all(itemgetter(*chk)(options))`

Answer (score 1):

Используй метод get

```
keys = ['gatewayUrl', 'clientId', 'secretKey']

options = {'gatewayUrl': '1', 'clientId':'2', 'secretKey':'3'}
False in [bool(options.get(key)) for key in keys]
>> False


options = {'gatewayUrl': '1', 'clientId':'2', 'secretKey':''}
False in [bool(options.get(key)) for key in keys]
>> True

options = {'gatewayUrl': '1', 'clientId':'2'}
False in [bool(options.get(key)) for key in keys]
>> True
```

То есть проверку на ключ и его не пустое значение можно записать так:

```
if False in [bool(options.get(key)) for key in keys]:
    raise
```